# Typeorm: query to get data from ManyToMany jointable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, typeorm

How do I get the `post` categories when returning the `user` data?

**Entity:**

```
@Entity()
export class Category extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;
}

@Entity()
export class Posts extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  content: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Category, (category) => category.id, [
    "insert",
    "update",
    "remove",
  ])
  @JoinColumn({ name: "post_categories" })
  categories: Category[];
}

@Entity("users")
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Posts)
  @JoinColumn()
  posts: Post;
}
```

**Query:**

```
await this.userRepository.findOne({
  where: { id }
});
```

This only returns the user model with posts but no categories:

```
{
  id: 1,
  email: 'foo@bar.com',
  posts: [
    {id: 1, title: 'test', content: 'lorem ipsum...'},
    {id: 1, title: 'test', content: 'lorem ipsum...'},
    {id: 1, title: 'test', content: 'lorem ipsum...'},
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `findOne` a `relations` array. Try

`await this.userRepository.findOne(id, { relations: ["categories"] });`